# creating a simple document management system

Tags: management, document

I have been asked to create a simple portfolio system for architects

the architect can create a document set of popular drawings, called a portfolio.

he can select individual documents (called folios) from their hard drive and they can set meta data for these folios.

they have given me a mockup which is a wire that forces the user to select the folios from the hard drive then set meta data for the individual folios *and* the portfolio in another step and then manage the folios in another step (1)

This to my mind fragments the process and I want it all done in one place (2)

[image]

the client is essentially advocating a facilitated walkthrough where the folios and portfolio are created in a number of steps.

My question:
what are the advantages of the clients solution? wouldnt it be better to have one standard interface where everyting is handled in the same place without these extra creation steps?

***you should consider folios as exactly the same as a file, its just that the client uses the term folio lots and is familiar with it.

Comment: Have you put this question to the client at all? Have they provided any rationale for the way they have suggested doing it? I wonder if they are suggesting that solution because that's how it's been done in the past and not necessarily because it's really the most efficient.

Comment: dont know yet. I have deadlines so I'm pressing ahead

Answer (score 1):

This looks like SharePoint where you first need to define the Document Set and its properties of metadata before you can upload or create folios. This is standard behavior, but I have trouble with the fact that they add metadata before they upload folios. It may very well be general built in document metadata such as creation date and author. However, more specific metadata, such as location and organization, may be difficult to attach to the document before it’s inside the DMS. Maybe I’ve misinterpreted their image.

However, even if you plan to move everything to a single step, these things need to be performed. Therefore, I see no real reason putting it all in a single-step-do-it-all. I guess they repeat step 1:3 a lot where they don’t have to build structure and set metadata. I think you’re better off keeping their way of structuring to minimize confusion.